# Shopify Import Bundle Install Not Working

Tags: import, rubygems, shopify

I'm trying to add @import to my Shopify theme development workflow via this [guide on Github here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-css-import).

Following the **Grunt.js** guide, I get as far as Step #5 when I'm supposed to run `bundle install`. When running this I get the following error:

```
Fetching git@github.com:Shopify/shopify_theme.git
Cloning into bare repository '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/shopify_theme-3de0c1fc88f476e318398688d2f3d8495e4f5062'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

It's also giving me an error of:

```
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory
```

Any ideas what's gone wrong? Still fairly new to the command line and can't work out what the issue might be.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it had something to do with linking an SSH key from my computer to my Github account. Followed this guide here, ran `bundle install` and now I shall party hard. https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github